# Why does this makefile build every dependency, every time?

Tags: makefile, stata

I'm using a makefile to run several Stata files that work with text files, other datasets, etc. **Every time I run make, it runs `analysis.do`, even if I make no changes to any of the dependencies.**
Here is the makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean spotless

STATACOMMAND=/opt/stata/stata-mp -b

analysis.txt: analysis.do uniform.dta normal.dta
    $(STATACOMMAND) analysis.do

uniform.dta: uniform.do
    $(STATACOMMAND) uniform.do

normal.dta: normal.do noise.txt
    $(STATACOMMAND) normal.do

clean:
    -rm *.log

spotless: clean
    -rm analysis.txt
    -rm *.dta
```

analysis.do

```
use normal.dta, clear
merge t using uniform.dta
log using analysis.txt, text
regress norm unif
log close
```

normal.do

```
clear
insheet using "noise.txt", clear
gen t = _n
gen norm = rnormal()
sort t
save normal.dta, replace
```

uniform.do

```
clear
set obs 10
gen t = _n
gen unif = runiform()
sort t
save uniform.dta, replace
```

noise.txt

```
noise
14
49
59
63
55
13
60
54
26
39
```

My actual code has a lot more files that exhibit this problem, but I'm hoping this simple example will at least help me narrow it down.

UPDATE: Are file modifications times somehow not being updated? I see these messages at the end of `make -d` every time I run the makefile:

```
Finished prerequisites of target file `analysis.txt'.
 Prerequisite `analysis.do' is older than target `analysis.txt'.
 Prerequisite `uniform.dta' is newer than target `analysis.txt'.
 Prerequisite `normal.dta' is newer than target `analysis.txt'.
Must remake target `analysis.txt'.
```

Here is another example. Let's say I've run `make` a few times. Here are the file modification times:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  105 Mar  1 19:25 analysis.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1.1K Mar  2 13:26 analysis.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1.5K Mar  1 19:25 analysis.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  317 Mar  1 19:41 makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo   36 Mar  1 19:34 noise.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  103 Mar  1 19:33 normal.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  803 Mar  1 19:38 normal.dta
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1007 Mar  1 19:38 normal.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo   83 Mar  1 19:28 uniform.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  594 Mar  1 19:38 uniform.dta
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  991 Mar  1 19:38 uniform.log
```

After running `make` again, here are the times. No times change **except the `.log` files that are automatically generated by Stata.**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  105 Mar  1 19:25 analysis.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1.1K Mar  2 13:29 analysis.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1.5K Mar  1 19:25 analysis.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  317 Mar  1 19:41 makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo   36 Mar  1 19:34 noise.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  103 Mar  1 19:33 normal.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  803 Mar  1 19:38 normal.dta
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 1007 Mar  1 19:38 normal.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo   83 Mar  1 19:28 uniform.do
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  594 Mar  1 19:38 uniform.dta
-rw-r--r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  991 Mar  1 19:38 uniform.log
```

Could this be the problem?

Comment: You say it ebuilds `raw4.do` through `raw12.do`, but I see no rule to rebuild *any* of these targets (except maybe `raw9.do`, but that looks like a typo). And some of these rules almost certainly don't do what you think they do. what happens when you `make raw4.do`?

Comment: How do you create `dta/raw10b.dta` which is needed by `dta/finaldata.dta`?

Comment: @Beta Sorry, my initial statement was just wrong. It doesn't build the do files, it runs them. It rebuilds the dta files associated with those. If I run `make raw4.do`, it tells me nothing to be done.

Comment: @AlexCohn @AlexCohn My understanding was that when make looks to build `dta/finaldata`, it sees `dta/raw10b.dta` as a dependency, so it jumps to that rule. It sees `dta/raw10a.dta` as a dependency, so it looks at its rule. Seeing that rule, it runs `raw10.do`, which builds both `dta/raw10a.dta` and `dta/raw10b.dta`. Would it make more sense to have the rule be like the version in my edit?

Comment: Why do you need `dta/raw10a.dta` as a target at all? At any rate, the edit does make sense: if `$(STATA) raw10.do` builds (among other outputs) `dta/raw10a.dtb`, it should be a rule for  `dta/raw10a.dtb`.

Comment: But probably the same pattern is used again: why do you need the `raw10datasource/%.txt: ;` empty rule? I'd simply drop this and similar rules.

Comment: @AlexCohn Even when I drop the empty rules and test the other targets in isolation, the problem still persists. Is there a nuance to make that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are you sure that command `/usr/local/stata/stata-mp -b raw3.do` does refresh the file `dta/raw3.dta`?

Comment: @AlexCohn I think I've narrowed the makefile down to a smaller makefile that demonstrates the problem, so should I edit my question down substantially, or just ask a new question?

Comment: If the answer to narrowed down question is expected to solve the original question, I'd suggest not asking a new one

Comment: @AlexCohn I updated the question with a simple example. Hopefully that will help narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with **stata**. I have never used this tool, but looking at their [documentation](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?log), you should probably try `analysis.log` instead of `analysis.txt`, and the following script:

```
use normal.dta, clear
merge t using uniform.dta
log using analysis, replace text
regress norm unif
log close
```

Comment: The `replace` keyword was the problem in this version of the question. I found the error in my previous question (before my last major edit) and found that it was unrelated to this. Not sure how to proceed in this case, but I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem:

```
dta/raw4a.dta dta/raw4b.dta: raw4.do raw4datasource/ftp/%.csv
    $(STATA) raw4.do

raw4datasource/ftp/%.csv: ;
```

The first rule doesn't do what you think. There is a '%' in the prerequisite list, but not in the targets. *It is not a pattern rule.* These targets do not depend on all existing files (or buildable files) of the form `raw4datasource/ftp/{something}.csv`, they depend on the target **`raw4datasource/ftp/%.csv`**. That's right, a file that has a `%` in its name. That file does not exist. And it will not be built, because the second rule does nothing.

I see four rules like this, and other things depend on them.

You must rethink the design of these rules; decide what you want them to do, figure out how to get them to work, and *test them in isolation before you try to hook them into the rest of the makefile*.

Comment: My goal is to have a target rule that depends on all files of the form  `raw4datasource/ftp/{something}.csv`. Is that not possible, or is there a different wildcard character I should be using?

Comment: According to [documentation](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_4.html) I'm reading, `*` is the proper wildcard character, so I'll update the makefile to take that into account, test the rules in isolation, and post again.

Comment: I updated my question to a much simpler example that also demonstrates the problem, so I hope that helps narrow the problem somewhat.

Comment: Do you want a rule that depends on all files of a certain form, or an explanation of why Make runs `stata` even when you haven't modified anything?

Comment: I realized that in my initial example, my dependencies were incorrect in the makefile, which led to confusion on my part. Everything seems to be working at the moment.